# How to put my api online?

Tags: php, android, api, amazon-web-services, slim

I've created an api using Slim framework. It's locally and i need to put it online, but I don't know how. I'm using mysql database to store the data, this api will be used for mobile application and website.

What is the best solution? And how I could do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make it accessible via the internet. This can be either the IP directly, or more commonly, via a domain name which points to your server which is hosting your API. If it's to be used strictly internally (by your own apps) you can avoid the cost of a domain name by using direct IP access. The IP must be externally accessible (not a LAN IP). You can use something like AWS or a a VPS service to host the database and API code.

For example: You get a VPS service from someone like FDC Net. They will supply you with an IP address. You install the API and database on that server. At this point you are good to go. You can access your API at the IP address that the provider gave you.

If you chose to go the AWS route (or google or MS or GoDaddy, etc) the procedure is similar. You will get an IP address where you can install. Typically you will have to modify your firewall settings here to open the ports you need. These services believe is closed access until needed.

To be honest, there is no "best" solution. The costs are roughly the same, the speed is roughly the same. It comes down to what you are most comfortable with. I would lean towards AWS (or something similar) since they appear to have the best uptime over VPS services.